# Change assign a word to a color in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text, colors, keyword

I want to assign a color to every text that contain some letters **in Eclipse**

e.g :

```
myclassTest
myclassRun
myclassHello
```

I would like that every worlds that contain "myclass" be green.

Or if it's not possible, how to assing some word to a color like :

```
 keyword <--green
 test <-- blue
```

Everytime I write keyword, this word should be green, etc.

**EDIT :**

what I 've tried ?: I 've searched everywhere in the eclipse preferences and I didn't found how to do it.

Comment: If you're talking about syntax color, this isn't the right site for that question.

Comment: sorry, what is the good site ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please update your question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: I ve searched everywhere in the editor.

Comment: Are you writing a new editor or just trying to do this in the default plain text editor (which does not support this)?

Comment: @greg-449, I said in Eclipse, I don't know if you know this editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For programming in color, this can be found in most developing suites such as Eclipse, which is a free java programming environment.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

*Only reserved words such as 'Class', 'private', 'static' etc will show up colored in an editor.*

**You can the colors in Eclipse by going to 'Window'->'Prferences', then 'Java'->'Editor'->'Syntax Coloring'.**

Comment: Why this answer ? did you read my question and the title ?, I want to know how to assign a specific text to a color, what you tell me to download eclipse ?

Comment: @user2372006 Only reserved words such as 'Class', 'private', 'static' etc will show up colored in an editor. You can the colors in Eclipse  by going to 'Window'->'Prferences', then 'Java'->'Editor'->'Syntax Coloring'.

Comment: Why the down vote? The question got changed to state 'Eclipse'

Comment: @user2372006 Not when I had answered it originally.

Comment: I've added "in Eclipse" inside the post after for YOU. But it was written already in the title and the tag I swear !

Comment: Thanks you for your edit, this will also help me. Since it's not possible to change a specific text I can't set your answer as the solution, but It's good to know